# How to pass property to component used in main.js from other components in vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Basically I want to a `loadingbar` component globally (included in app template) 
Here is my `loadingbar` component

```
<template>
    <div class="loadingbar" v-if="isLoading">
        Loading ...
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'loadingbar',
    props: ['isLoading'],
    data () {
        return {

        }
    }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

and in `main.js`, I have included this component as

```
import LoadingBar from './components/LoadingBar.vue';
new Vue({
    router,
    data () {
        return {
            isLoading: true
        };
    },
    methods: {
    },
    created: function () {
    },
    components: {
        LoadingBar
    },
    template: `
        <div id="app">
            <LoadingBar :isLoading="isLoading"/>
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    `
}).$mount('#app');
```

My aim is to show loading component based upon the value of variable `isLoading`. The above code working fine. But I want to use set `isLoading` variable from other component (so that to decide whether to show `loading` component). Eg. In **post components**

```
<template>
    <div class="post container">

    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'post',
    data () {
        return {
            posts: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        fetchPosts: function() {
            // to show loading bar 
            this.isLoading = true;
            this.$http.get(APIURL+'listpost')
                .then(function(response) {
                    // to hide loading bar 
                    this.isLoading = false;
                    console.log("content loaded");
                });
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        this.fetchPosts();
    }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

Of coarse we can't access `isLoading` directly from `main.js` so i decided to use `Mixin` so i put following code in `main.js`

```
Vue.mixin({
    data: function () {
        return {
            isLoading: false
        };
    }
});
```

This however allow me to access `isLoading` from any other component but I can't modify this variable. Can any help me to achieve this?

> Note: I know i can achieve this by including `loadingbar` in individual component (I tried that and it was working fine, But i do not want to do that as `loadingbar` is needed in every component so i was including in main template/component)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/) like so:

```
// main.js 
import Vuex from 'vuex'
let store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    isLoading: false,
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_IS_LOADING(state, value) {
      state.isLoading = value;
    }
  },
  getters: {
    isLoading(state) {
      return state.isLoading;
    }
  }
})

import LoadingBar from './components/LoadingBar.vue';
new Vue({
  router,
  store, // notice you need to add the `store` var here
  components: {
    LoadingBar
  },
  template: `
    <div id="app">
        <LoadingBar :isLoading="$store.getters.isLoading"/>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  `
}).$mount('#app');
```

```javascript
// script of any child component
methods: {
  fetchPosts: function() {
    // to show loading bar 
    this.$store.commit('SET_IS_LOADING', true);
    this.$http.get(APIURL+'listpost')
      .then(function(response) {
        // to hide loading bar 
        this.$store.commit('SET_IS_LOADING', false);
        console.log("content loaded");
      });
  }
},
```

Comment: I think i should go with the second way, but why we have to pass `store` in second way (on line `store, // notice you need to add the `store` var here`);
It is not defined in this example

Comment: You don't need to I forget to take it out when I copy/pasted. Edited now

Comment: yup, i have tried the same way, and it is show the correct value but some how the `loadingbar` is not included

Comment: Also if try the same for in main.js (setting `this.$isLoading = true;` before `$http.get` call and then set `this.$isLoading = false;` after that), it sets correct value. but again `loadingbar` shown but not get hidden after getting the data through `$http.get`. I think Vue can't observe object prototype

Comment: Huh, I'm not sure why that doesn't work, I can look into it later. For now I've edited my post to include the solution I know will work.

Comment: Thanks, i will go with the above solution if i don't find any other simple solution